# To what extent is file metadata encrypted on Mega.co.nz?

Tags: mega

How much of the file metadata of files that I upload to Mega.co.nz encrypted (and therefore unreadable for Mega on the server)?

Are the filenames of files encrypted?

I assume that the file sizes are not hidden, is this right?

What about folder names, and folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

An explanation of the MEGA cryptography can be found in the [MEGA developer's documentation](https://mega.co.nz/#doc) in the "Under the Hood" section.

> All symmetric cryptographic operations are based on AES-128. It operates in cipher block chaining mode for the file and folder attribute blocks and in counter mode for the actual file data. Each file and each folder node uses its own randomly generated 128 bit key. File nodes use the same key for the attribute block and the file data, plus a 64 bit random counter start value and a 64 bit meta MAC to verify the file's integrity.

From this, you can deduce:

- Directory structures are encrypted through the use of encrypted nodes
- File & folder names (and other attributes) are encrypted in attribute blocks

File and folder sizes although not encrypted, will be obscured. That is, without knowledge of the file/folder names or structure, you can only guess the total size of the encrypted data.